# Html geolocation not working on my mobile web application | Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring-mvc

I'm developing a mobile web application with Spring MVC. For geolocation, I get the code from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)

I ran the demo from my phone on that site and it's asking for location permission, same thing on jsfiddle demo, and it's working. If I don't have Gps enable I get '"Unable to retrieve your location'.

But on my application, I get instantly the above message, without asking for permission(also, removed all blocked apps from chrome).

On PC, geolocation is working,through my app, but on my phone, not.. What can be the problem?Meaning.. why geolocation is not working on my phone through my app, but it's working for other sites. On my phone, goes directly to error() function.
Maybe I have to make some changes in the configuration files,or I don't know..

LE: Tested on 2 more devices, same output:Unable to retrieve your location ... (GPS enabled)

LE2:**I checked the error code. I'm getting permission denied**
[This is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/)

```
<p><button onclick="geoFindMe()">Show my location</button></p>
<div id="out"></div>

//Javascript
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

    output.appendChild(img);
  };

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  };

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

Comment: could you include the jsFiddle link to which you're referring and have you created your own example in fiddle?

Comment: I edited, my post. It's mozzila's fiddle, which works on my phone. But accessing it on my phone through my app..it didn't work

Comment: I checked the error code. I'm getting permission denied

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code, 
https://github.com/makubex88/MobileHTML5CodeCamp/blob/master/mobilehtml5.html

```
    function showPosition(position) {
            var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
            var img_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
            document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML = "<img src='" + img_url + "'>";
        }
```

Comment: It won't work, on my phone I instantly get permission dennied. And my app is not displayed on blocked apps, on chrome

Comment: does it open in your web browser?

Comment: It's the same thing as above.. retrieving position.coords.latitude and longitude..So, I'm sure, the output will be the same. I'm running my app through localhost

Comment: what browser are you using in your phone?

Comment: Google Chrome. Just tested on Mozzila and it's asking for permissions :|

Comment: html5 geolocation really asking for user's permission because of possible privacy compromise issue. In Chrome, you can configure it in chrome://settings/content, Location, allow all sites to track your physical location

Comment: I have problem on Android Chrome, where I can't access that link, also, can't 'allow all sites to track your physical location '

Comment: this will run the html5 page https://rawgit.com/makubex88/MobileHTML5CodeCamp/master/mobilehtml5.html and will ask for your location when you click the Try it button in Geolocation, do you mean that settings has disabled in your phone?

Comment: it's working for other sites..not working for my localhost